# Paragraphs in Org

Tags: org-mode

I often take notes about some techniques or similar stuff and list advantages and disadvantages in the end. If I just write

```
Some description.

Advantages:
- first item
- second item

Disadvantages:
- first item
- second item
```

, it looks bad after exporting it to PDF via LaTeX:

[image]

To avoid this problem, I use the LaTeX command `\paragraph`:

```
Some description.

\paragraph{Advantages:}
- first item
- second item

\paragraph{Disadvantages:}
- first item
- second item
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this directly in Org (like the bullet lists which are integrated into Org)?

Because it was requested, here is the document I'm currently working on: https://pastebin.com/LxhrJc44 It can server as an example of what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to format your notes using headings:

```
Some description.

* Advantages:
- first item
- second item

* Disadvantages:
- first item
- second item
```

and then setting:

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil
```

in your org file so that the export produces unnumbered sections.

Comment: I don't want to use headings for that because I use headings for structuring. Furthermore, I'd have to skip headings to make sure that the current heading is a paragraph in the LaTeX export. Your example does not yield paragraphs but sections because you only used single asterisks.

Comment: I suggest you expand your question to show the full structure of your org file in that case.

Comment: @UTF-8 Please see at first what paragraphs are in org-mode: https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Paragraphs. There is no special "paragraph" heading. The approach of this answer looks very promising to me especially with `#+OPTIONS: num:nil`.

Comment: @Tobias I didn't mean those paragraphs but the LaTeX command `\paragraph`. It's not about some specific document but about the general concept. I want to use sections for structuring. Anyway, I added the document I'm currently working on in its current state to the question. Good luck dealing with my messy lecture notes which – to make things worse – are in German. ^^

Comment: @UTF-8 You could use lists with two hierarchies. First hierarchy is `Advantages/Disadvantages` second hierarchy are the actual items.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add the following at the beginning of your Org document:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{enumitem}\setlist[itemize]{nosep}
```

Note that the `enumitem` LaTeX package allows for a plethora of options, which you can adapt to your specific taste.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, I think that you misunderstood the question. The problem got nothing to do with vertical spacing. It want "Advantages" and "Disadvantages" to be bold (or "Vorteile" and "Nachteile" in my German document or whatever) and I want the list to be indented relative to those labels. This is exactly what the LaTeX command `\paragraph` does which is why i use it. My question is whether there is a good way to do this in Org without explicitly writing the command `\paragraph`. Of course, I could misuse sectioning as already proposed, but that wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: If you just want bold text, you can just write these words `*like this*`.

Comment: Doesn't solve the indentation problem. There also are other use cases for LaTeX paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this seems to be the standard "indentation of a first line of a paragraph in a section (other than the first)" problem.

You can try \noindent:

```
\noindent Advantages:
 - foo
 - bar
```

or if you want to set it globally, you can try setting the parindent to 0:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```